# Jquery AJAX request on SSL

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl, https, certificate

I am trying to make an AJAX request using JQuery to a server on SSL using HTTPS. The server uses Basic HTTP authentication.
The code is

```
url=jwvmbaseurl+url;
$.ajax
({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', jwvmauthheader); 
    },
    success: successmethod
});
```

The request returns 500 Server error from Server. I don't have access to server. 
If I straight away type the URL from firebug into address bar it works fine, just that I have to ignore certifiate validation failure and provide basic credentials.

Also, I have CORS enabled on the server, so same origin policy should not be the problem.

Let me know how to solve the problem

Comment: can you elaborate what are you passing as the url attribute, I think the url is not constructed correctly.

Comment: URL is constructed correctly. Copy paste to address bar from firbug works correctly. The URL is https://10.65.157.115:8443/restserv/user/